# Problema al introducir informacion en base de datos usando Postman

Tags: php, json, post, postman

Estoy tratando de realizar unas funciones a través de un servicio web, listar unas actividades almacenadas en una base de datos y crear mas actividades. Estoy utilizando Postman para mandar la información por el post y rellenar las nuevas actividades modificando el body en formato Json, pero al mandar la petición me devuelve el siguiente error en vez de la actividad en formato json:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según mi código php es un  error que tengo recogido a la hora de ejecutar el statement, pero me dice que el campo título de la actividad es null. Tengo la impresión de que me dará el mismo error con todos los campos y no sé porqué ocurre.
este es el código de la función:

```
function crearActividad()
{
    $actividad = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    global $conexion_mysql;

    // SQL
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO actividades (titulo, fecha, ciudad, tipo, coste, usuario) 
                 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    // Creamos sentencia preparada
    $stmt = $conexion_mysql->prepare($consulta);
    // Comprobamos que este bien la sentencia preparada
    if (!$stmt) {
        exit('Sentencia prepare() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars(($conexion_mysql->prepare($consulta))->error_));
    }
    // Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parámetros
    $resultado = $stmt->bind_param(
        'ssssds',

        $actividad["titulo"],
        $actividad["fecha"],
        $actividad["ciudad"],
        $actividad["tipo"],
        $actividad["coste"],
        $actividad["usuario"],
    );
    // Comprobamos que este bien los tipos y variables en nuestro bind.
    if (!$resultado) {
        exit('bind_param() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    // Ejecutamos resultado
    $resultado = $stmt->execute();
    // Comprobamos que se haya ejecutado correctamente
    if (!$resultado) {
        exit('execute() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    if ($resultado) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

Dejo también el index para que veáis desde dónde se está ejecutando :

```
<?php
require 'actividades.php';
//peticiones

$tipo_solicitud = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

switch($tipo_solicitud){

    case "GET":
        listarActividades();
        break;
    case "POST":
        crearActividad();
        break;

}
```

Gracias!!

Comment: No veo los datos que intentas mandar al servidor: título, fecha, ciudad, etc. ¿Dónde están esos datos?

Comment: Según el ejemplo en el que meestoy basando, los datos de cada campo los debo introucir en el cuerpo del archivo en formato Json que se debería mostrar en Postman. En su lugar, recibo el mensaje de error.

Comment: @A.Cedano, nevermind, ya he visto el problema, es la primera vez que uso Postman y no había visto el cuadro de texto donde tenía que introducir los datos... Gracias igualemente

Comment: Por eso mismo te pregunté por los datos. También, si en el diseño de la tabla a la que quieres insertar hay campos con restricción `NOT NULL` conviene que verifiques si esos campos fueron pasados, de modo que escribas un código coherente con la capa de datos. Desde PHP 7 puedes usar el operador de fusión de null para ello. Si fuera tú crearía variables a partir de todos los valores usando fusión de null, para evitar advertencias del tipo *`Undefined index`* Digo esto porque en `bind_param` tú entras a lo bruto con los datos creyendo ingenuamente que todos esos datos serán pasados al servidor.